# jQuery Mobile onclick assignments in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, click

I have noted a peculiar problem with onclick event assignments in IE9 - they do not work until after the Developer tools panel has been opened.  After it has been opened the cliks work and continue to do so even after the dev tools panel is closed.  Is there a known issue here?  Would it help to bind to the click event dynamically, e.g. in the pageshow event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone else running into this thread - the fact is that IE chokes if the JavaScript function responding to a click issues a console.log() if the IE Developer pane is not open.  This does not happen with any of the other browsers.  With IE one innocent console.log and your entire enterprise comes to a grinding halt.

I was dimly aware of the console issue from the distant past but - like any sane developer - given that I don't debug with IE (and wish  I could dismember it, then burn the remains and pretend it never existed) I had forgotten about this.